# imu stack tutorial non-functional

Tags: ros, imu, tutorial, stack, microstrain

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have attempted to follow the directions in the imu_node tutorial and step 1.1 (compiling) appears to be broken.  I am running ROS electric on Ubuntu 10.10.

The following command:

rosdep install microstrain_3dmgx2_imu

returns the following error:

Warning: could not identify ['microstrain_3dmgx2_imu'] as a package

Any assistance is appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29606/imu-stack-tutorial-non-functional/) by [mblanton](https://answers.ros.org/users/1956/mblanton/) on ROS Answers with karma: 118 on 2012-03-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Enrique](https://answers.ros.org/users/244/enrique/) on 2012-03-13**:
In ubuntu you can install it from apt: sudo apt-get install ros-electric-imu-drivers, then roscd microstrain_3dmgx2_imu, and you can omit rosdep and rosmake steps, as everything is already built. You should be able to rosrun the imu_node directly.

**Comment by [mblanton](https://answers.ros.org/users/1956/mblanton/) on 2012-03-14**:
Thanks Enrique!  That worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From @Enrique's comment:
In ubuntu you can install it from apt: sudo apt-get install ros-electric-imu-drivers, then roscd microstrain_3dmgx2_imu, and you can omit rosdep and rosmake steps, as everything is already built. You should be able to rosrun the imu_node directly.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2